# How can I compare a letter from a string in C?

Tags: c

```
char* str = "Hello"

if ( str[0] == 'a' ) {
  printf("OK");
}
```

I tried this but get an error, how am i suppose to comapre them?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @CarlosGarcia "expected expression before if"

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon after `"Hello"`:

```
    char* str = "Hello";

    if ( str[0] == 'H' ) {
      printf("OK");
    }
```